# Is it possible to use a map key as an attribute and its value as attribute value in a terraform config block?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to pass key, value pair to a resource and using the key as an attribute and its value as attributes value. But it throws an error message

```
each.key = each.value

An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
variable "k8s_labels" {
  description = "Kubernetes labels to set for the node pool."
  type = map
  default = {
    label1 = "value1",
    label2 = "value2",
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  .
  .
  .
  dynamic "labels" {
    for_each = var.k8s_labels
    content {
      each.key = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try `content = {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a dynamic content block, the name of the temporary lambda iterator variable is not `each`, but rather the name of the block itself. In this case, that would be `labels`. Additionally, the labels block must be enclosed within a `node_config` block according to the [schema documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#labels). These fixes in combination will resolve your issue.

You can update your dynamic content block like:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  ...

  node_config {
    dynamic "labels" {
      for_each = var.k8s_labels

      content {
        labels.key = labels.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This helps to distinguish the temporary lambda iterator variable within the scope of the dynamic block from one within the scope of the resource itself. If iterating within the scope of the resource:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  for_each = var.foo # var.foo of type Map
}
```

then those key-value pairs would be accessible within the dynamic content blocks also with `each.key` and `each.value`. This avoids variable naming collision within the scope of the dynamic content block.

You can check the [dynamic block documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) for more information, including how to rename the variable with the `iterator` argument.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried as you suggested and get same error again
`
terraform validate

Error: Argument or block definition required

  on modules/gke/node_pool/resources.tf line 56, in resource "google_container_node_pool" "default":
  56:         labels.key = labels.value

An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
`

Comment: @RandomQuests I just checked the documentation for the `gcp` provider and found the issue. Updating answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not support dynamically generating argument names inside a block. Argument names are similar to struct or class fields in a statically-typed programming language, rather than keys in a map, so you must write them out individually and then Terraform will validate that all of the names are valid in that context.

The good news for your situation here though is that this `labels` argument seems to actually be an argument of type map, rather than a block type, and so you don't need to do anything special to set it dynamically: you can literally just assign your map of strings to it, because it's already a value of the type expected for that argument:

```
variable "k8s_labels" {
  description = "Kubernetes labels to set for the node pool."
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    label1 = "value1",
    label2 = "value2",
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  # ...

  node_config {
    # ...

    labels = var.k8s_labels
  }
}
```

The use of `dynamic` blocks only applies to situations where you need to dynamically generate zero or more nested blocks, which typically represent nested objects that in some sense belong to the resource they are nested inside. For `google_container_node_pool`, `node_config` is a nested block type, and `labels` is an argument that the provider has declared for that nested block type, declaring it as expecting a `map(string)` value.